# How are Component.spec.tsx files used in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm reading through some of the code in the Material UI React library. My question is around the usage of `Component.spec.tsx`, specifically the spec file [Like this](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/ab2cb8cf9614ccab02b62a22de5129a1c2774d96/packages/mui-joy/src/FormLabel/FormLabel.spec.tsx).

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import FormLabel, { FormLabelOwnerState } from '@mui/joy/FormLabel';
import { expectType } from '@mui/types';

<FormLabel component="div" />;

<FormLabel data-testid="any" />;

<FormLabel
  slots={{
    root: 'div',
    asterisk: 'div',
  }}
/>;

<FormLabel
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      component: 'div',
      'data-testid': 'test',
    },
    asterisk: {
      component: 'div',
      'data-testid': 'test',
    },
  }}
/>;
```

Questions

1. What is the use case for a `*.spec.tsx` file?
2. Why are components declared at the top level of the file?
3. Is there anything I can read that documents this practice?

I've can read in the `jest` docs that indicate a spec file is an alternative to a `test.tsx` file.

Answer (score 0):

These files are used to test type definitions. They are not a part of the production bundle but are compiled with TypeScript, showing potential problems with types.

Calling them *.spec.tsx is just a convention.

Comment: Ok, so all they do is build to check for errors and are then thrown away. Makes sense! Where did the concept of having these files come from? I'd never seen them anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know if this pattern was invented at MUI or taken from elsewhere.

Comment: @denski, Ada has spec.ada and body.ada files.